# Possible misprint in this proof of a basic metatheorem of FOL ( Shapiro, Classical Logic)

Tags: logic, soft-question, solution-verification, first-order-logic

In the proof below , should not we have

" then **$\phi$ is $\psi\& \chi$ and $\Gamma_1 |- \psi \&\chi$** "

instead of

"Then ϕ is ψ&χ, and Γ1⊢**ϕ&χ**" ?

The original text is ( https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Dedu) :

> Lemma 7. If Γ1 and Γ2 differ only in that wherever Γ1 contains θ, Γ2
> contains θ(t|t′), then for any sentence ϕ not containing t or t′, if
> Γ1⊢ϕ then Γ2⊢ϕ
>
> .
>
> **Proof**: The proof proceeds by induction on the number of steps in the proof of ϕ. Crucial to this proof is the fact that θ=θ(t|t′)
> whenever θ does not contain t or t′.
>
> - When the number of steps in the proof of ϕ is one, this means that the last (and only) rule applied is (As) or (=I). Then, since ϕ does
>   not contain t or t′, if Γ1⊢ϕ we simply apply the same rule ((As) or
>   (=I)) to Γ2 to get Γ2⊢ϕ.
> - Assume that there are n>1 steps in the proof of ϕ, and that Lemma 7 holds for any proof with less than n steps. Suppose that the nth rule
>   applied to Γ1 was (&I). **Then ϕ is ψ&χ, and Γ1⊢ϕ&χ.** But then we
>   know that previous steps in the proof include Γ1⊢ψ and Γ1⊢χ, and by
>   induction, we have Γ2⊢ψ and Γ2⊢χ, since neither ψ nor χ contain t or
>   t′. So, we simply apply (&I) to Γ2 to get Γ2⊢ψ&χ as required. Suppose
>   now that the last step applied in the proof of Γ1⊢ϕ was (&E). Then, at
>   a previous step in the proof of ϕ, we know Γ1⊢ϕ&ψ for some sentence ψ.
>   If ψ does not contain t, then we simply apply (&E) to Γ2 to obtain the
>   desired result. The only complication is if ψ contains t. Then we
>   would have that Γ2⊢(ϕ&ψ)(t|t′). But, since (ϕ&ψ)(t|t′) is
>   ϕ(t|t′)&ψ(t|t′), and ϕ(t|t′) is just ϕ, we can just apply (&E) to get
>   Γ2⊢ϕ as required. The cases for the other rules are similar.

Comment: Yes, it is a typo.

Comment: Thanks @MauroAllegranza